# ACS75005 "The request is not a valid SAML2 protocol message." Is showing always when I connect to Windows Azure Active Directory using SAML

Tags: .net, azure, saml-2.0

I'm trying to consume Windows Azure Active Directory as an IdP in a web application. My code works fine on other SAML IdPs but gives the following message in the Windows Azure AD only !!

> Sign in
>
> Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in.
>
> We received a bad request.
> Additional technical information:
>
> Trace ID:8377e605-6b9f-47be-8547-5fce7f4285af
>
> Timestamp: 2014-08-04 13:31:27Z
>
> ACS75005:
>
> The request is not a valid SAML2 protocol message.

I replaced my code and used the SAML request that Microsoft published [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dn195589.aspx) and replaced only some values but still getting the same error message !!

What is wrong with my request? And how can I get more details about the message !

Knowing that my application is defined in the Windows Azure AD applications.

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" ID="_56dbfeac-107a-46d2-b989-651f90107312" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2014-08-04T13:28:05Z" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">SOMETHING</Issuer> 
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

**Edit 001**
After editing the assertion to be as Dushyant suggested, it becomes:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
    ID="_efcebb45-5ee6-42df-ace4-a343f28f5a46"                                                 
    Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2014-08-07T06:29:09Z"                                                 
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">                                    
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">SOMETHING</Issuer>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

But still the same error is showing!

Also please find the test project I'm using [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5A_7cLniRoxQkJsZDR1S0lINDQ/edit?usp=sharing). Only replace the values in the AppSettings in the webconfig for your SAML settings.

Comment: I found the problem. Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Meh! Dead links. On StackOverflow it's best to inline everything.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use

```
xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
```

instead of xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"

I believe you followed what we've document here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn195589.aspx. If so, you've found a bug in that article - sorry about that.

Hope this helps.

---

Homam, I reviewed your code. The problem was with the way the AuthnRequest was being encoded. I changed it to standard deflate encoding and it worked.

```
public string GetAzureRequest(AuthRequestFormat format)
{
    string xml = @"<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"" ID=""#ID""
                                     Version=""2.0"" IssueInstant=""#DATE""
                                     xmlns:samlp=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"">
                        <Issuer xmlns=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"">#ISSUER</Issuer>
                 </samlp:AuthnRequest>";

    xml = xml.Replace("#DATE", issue_instant);
    xml = xml.Replace("#ID", id);
    xml = xml.Replace("#ISSUER", appSettings.Issuer);
    xml = xml.Replace("\r\n", "");

    if (format == AuthRequestFormat.Base64)
    {
        /*COMMENTED THIS OUT*/

        //byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestDocument.OuterXml);
        //string result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
        //return result;


        /*ADDED THIS*/

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new DeflateStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true), new UTF8Encoding(false));
        writer.Write(xml);
        writer.Close();
        string result = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Still the same error with no details :(
Please help me until I fix it.

Comment: Edited the question.. the update is under "**Edit 001**"

Comment: I also added the sample code that I'm using to the question

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been struggling to figure out a solution to compose the SAMLRequest querystring for Azure AD sign in request. This code worked..!

Answer (score 0):

You need to UrlEncode (e.g. HttpUtility.UrlEncode(result)) the 'result' before using it in a Get request.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a mismatch in namespaces here...The SAMLRequest should look like this.

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest
    ID="_efcebb45-5ee6-42df-ace4-a343f28f5a46"                                                 
    Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2014-08-07T06:29:09Z"                                                 
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">                                    
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">SOMETHING</Issuer>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

The Issuer element must be in the namespace of 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion' and the AuthnRequest element within the namespace of 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol'

Of course this needs to be deflated + base64 encoded. If using HttpRedirect binding then also urlencode this before embedding within the URL