# AADSTS75005: The request is not a valid Saml2 protocol message.

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I have a SAML implementation which works fine with JumpCloud, OneLogin and other providers, however integration with Microsoft Azure AD is proving difficult.  We received the error

```
AADSTS75005: The request is not a valid Saml2 protocol message.
```

Whenever we send our requests over.  I have tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120025/acs75005-the-request-is-not-a-valid-saml2-protocol-message-is-showing-always) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591257/correct-authnrequest-to-azure-ad-idp) but neither fixes the issue for us.

My code to create the SAML Request, which opens in a new window via some Javascript is:

```
Using sw As StringWriter = New StringWriter()
    Dim xws As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
    xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = True

    Dim assertionUrl As String = "OUR URL"
    Dim issuer As String = "OUR ISSUER TEXT"
    dim id as string = "_" + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    dim issue_instant as string = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")

    Using xw As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sw, xws)
        xw.WriteStartElement("samlp", "AuthnRequest", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol")
        xw.WriteAttributeString("ID", id)
        xw.WriteAttributeString("Version", "2.0")
        xw.WriteAttributeString("IssueInstant", issue_instant)
        xw.WriteAttributeString("ProtocolBinding", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST")
        xw.WriteAttributeString("AssertionConsumerServiceURL", assertionUrl)

        xw.WriteStartElement("saml", "Issuer", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion")
        xw.WriteString(issuer)
        xw.WriteEndElement()

        xw.WriteStartElement("samlp", "NameIDPolicy", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol")
        xw.WriteAttributeString("Format", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:unspecified")
        xw.WriteAttributeString("AllowCreate", "true")
        xw.WriteEndElement()

        xw.WriteStartElement("samlp", "RequestedAuthnContext", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol")
        xw.WriteAttributeString("Comparison", "exact")

        xw.WriteStartElement("saml", "AuthnContextClassRef", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion")
        xw.WriteString("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport")
        xw.WriteEndElement()

        xw.WriteEndElement() ' RequestedAuthnContext

        xw.WriteEndElement()
    End Using

    If (format = AuthRequestFormat.Base64)
        Dim toEncodeAsBytes As Byte() = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sw.ToString())
        Return System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes)
    End If

    Return Nothing
End Using
```

We then redirect the user to: **https://login.microsoftonline.com/OUR_APP_ID/saml2?SAMLRequest=** followed by the encoded string

I have base64decoded my result, and read it as a raw string and the XML appears valid to me.  I have even gone so far as to take the example Request from Azure AD and hard-coded my implementation to that, with replaced issuer/instant/id etc.  This leads me to believe it is an encoding issue in my request.  However, the changed encoding in Dushyant Gill's answer does not resolve my problem either.

I've found various other forum posts where other software vendors have mentioned that they have had to apply changes to their SAML implementations when their customers have complained that it didn't work with Azure - however I've yet to find what their resolution was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using HTTP redirect binding (which is suggested by

> We then redirect the user to

) , then the SAMLRequest has to be encoded using DEFLATE encoding. Please see section 3.4.4 of http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply - I had followed the steps in Dushyant's answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120025/acs75005-the-request-is-not-a-valid-saml2-protocol-message-is-showing-always) and didn't have any luck.  I tried the same thing again today and of course now it works.  Should've slept on it :) You are indeed correct and this is the correct answer.